# trigger an event inside the website using an email external link (gmail, outlook)

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

Is it possible to trigger an event inside the website using an email external link(gmail, outlook). I have a sign up form that slides that in and out from the website using a button. Would it be possible if I click an email external link that sign up form would slide in once the page renders

Comment: Possible, and you don't need to trigger the event. Instead, add a query parameter to the URL, and check for its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just apply some specific *flag* in URL. E.g. `http://example.com/form.php#some-flag`

Than in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash == '#some-flag') {
        triggerEvent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Question what if the website has a `https://www.electricstudio.ph/#/` in the url initially. Tried applying your method for a web app built with `angular` but it doesn't seem to work. I even tried inserting the hash manually `https://www.electricstudio.ph/#/#some-flag`

Comment: @clestcruz Than `location.hash` will contain string `#/#some-flag`